NextJS Fomantic UI Library
I am new to ReactJS and NextJS.  I try adding Fomantic UI into my NextJS app but "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')" Server Error is raised when the page is using Fomantic library.  If the page not using it, no error is shown.
I install the library by following command:
   npm install --save fomantic-ui-css semantic-ui-react


and, create a very simple page but the error displayed:
import '../../node_modules/fomantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <Button primary>Click Here</Button>
    )
}


Thanks,

After search the NextJS document, I add a line:
'use client';

on top of the .tsx file to render the page on client side (browser) then the problem fixed.
